# Customizing when to capture stack trace in NLog

Tags: c#, .net, logging, nlog

I am writing a custom NLog target deriving from `TargetWithLayout`, and I would like to make it optionally write the stack trace, depending on the specific log event. I've defined a nested layout like this (syntax might not be correct):

```
Layout layout = "${when:${event-properties:StackTraceEnabled}==true:${stacktrace}}";
```

And I would be creating events like this:

```
var logEventInfo = new NLog.LogEventInfo(NLog.LogLevel.Error, "Test", "Test")
{
    Properties =
    {
        { "StackTraceEnabled", true },
    }
};
```

However, this doesn't work, and seems to go against the design of NLog. From the little I've seen, NLog evaluates a `GetStackTraceUsage()` against its registered targets, and then either always generates the stack trace or never does. Is this correct? Is there a way of customizing stack trace generation at event level?

Comment: Is this a performance thing or a rendering issue? As the latter should work - it's captured but should not be rendered when `StackTraceEnabled` == `false`

Comment: It's a performance consideration. I log info-level events 1000s of times a second, and I only want to capture the stack trace for a small fraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use two target instances, and just use the logger-name to control whether it should use the target configured to write StackTrace:

```
<logger name="StackTraceEnabled" writeTo="target1_stacktrace" final="true">
<logger name="*" writeTo="target2_default" />
```

Right now NLog decides only based on Logger-name whether it should include StackTrace (or not). It finds all logging-rules matching the logger-name, and if one includes a target with stacktrace then capture will be done (independent of the rule has condition-filters)

It should be easy to fix NLog so it also checks filter-conditions before trying to capture StackTrace (Allow filter-optimization on other stuff than logger-name).

Answer (score 0):

Confirming what the accepted answer stated: The `NLog.LoggerImpl.Write` internal method captures the stack trace if any NLog target requires the stack trace for any message (irrespective of filters), and if the `LogEventInfo` instance does not already have a stack trace. Per [LoggerImpl.cs](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/a4efaefce9d31c667225fa0bd72e08809308a9a1/src/NLog/LoggerImpl.cs#L46):

```
internal static class LoggerImpl
{
    internal static void Write([NotNull] Type loggerType, TargetWithFilterChain targets, LogEventInfo logEvent, LogFactory factory)
    {
        if (targets == null)
            return;

        StackTraceUsage stu = targets.GetStackTraceUsage();
        if (stu != StackTraceUsage.None && !logEvent.HasStackTrace)
        {
            var stackTrace = new StackTrace(StackTraceSkipMethods, stu == StackTraceUsage.WithSource);
            var stackFrames = stackTrace.GetFrames();
            int? firstUserFrame = FindCallingMethodOnStackTrace(stackFrames, loggerType);
            int? firstLegacyUserFrame = firstUserFrame.HasValue ? SkipToUserStackFrameLegacy(stackFrames, firstUserFrame.Value) : (int?)null;
            logEvent.GetCallSiteInformationInternal().SetStackTrace(stackTrace, firstUserFrame ?? 0, firstLegacyUserFrame);
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

The above method would refrain from capturing the actual stack trace if one had already been explicitly set, even if just a placeholder. Thus, explicitly setting the stack trace to a placeholder is the easiest way to prevent NLog from generating the stack trace for those specific log entries.